# Standard, open web application used for benchmarking

Tags: asp.net, testing, web-applications, benchmarking

Anybody know any existing 'open' Web Applications with Source and Data that are used for Benchmarking (e.g. Shopping site with kart).

Somebody is looking for something 'standard' that can be used as the subject of a performance tuning exercise.

e.g. - as it stood, the XXXX application managed 2000 req/sec on Kit Y running in NetFx 2 and Sql 2005 etc. Ideally with some standard defined tests too (e.g. 1 user buys three products and checks out, 1 user browses 6 products) etc..

Something like the TPC-W described here: 
http://www.tpc.org/tpcw/

Although TPC-W claims to be retired in '05. Also, no .NET source code is provided.

Anything like this out there? The source would have to be ASP.NET (MVC or WebForms) and the back end SQL.

Thanks

Comment: TPC-W was used in this test  And used in this test: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/5/26/end-to-end-performance-study-of-cloud-services.html Although TPC-W claims to be retired in '05. Also, no .NET source code is provided. 

Any suggestions?